# Making an efficient query with 7 joins, JPA or SQL? What type of collection?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, join

folks!

Had to performance tune an expensive JPA query with 7 joins, taking 42 seconds to complete locally and ~3 minutes in the remote server (AWS).

`SELECT res FROM Resultado res JOIN res.panoramica pan JOIN pan.gondolaId gon JOIN gon.visitaId vis JOIN vis.estabelecimentoId estab JOIN estab.cliente cli JOIN res.configuracaoAnalise ca JOIN vis.usuarioId usu`

Modified it into a complete native SQL query (selecting all fields associated with each table in the joins) and time decreased to less than a millisecond. When using this approach I lose the ease of JPA, since the method `fullQuery` returns `List<Object[]>`, but performance is really the most important thing.

When assigning the value (returned by `fullQuery`) to a List in the managed bean, it takes 10 seconds and the list has 200 thousand elements right now.

What would be the most recommended option in this case?

SOLVED:

Thanks to @dcsohl 's answer, it worked with the following:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
name="ResultadoJoin"
,entities={
    @EntityResult(entityClass=Resultado.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Panoramica.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=ConfiguracaoAnalise.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Gondola.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Visita.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Estabelecimento.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Usuario.class)
    ,@EntityResult(entityClass=Equipe.class)
    }
)
```

Comment: clearly JPA allows use of ON clauses in JOINs. Also indexes on join columns are specifiable via JPA. But then all is supposition since we see nothing

Comment: Option between JPA and SQL, plus the type of collection. The method `query.getResultList()` returns `java.util.List`.

Comment: You yourself have said that JPA is way too slow. So you have to do SQL. What, again, is the actual question here?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to tune that JPA query, that's why I asked that. 4 of those tables have one `LONGBLOB` field,

Comment: how can anyone say whether its possible to tune the JPQL ? to do that you'd have to post the JPQL, the SQL that the JPQL equates to, and the SQL you invoked yourself (as well as the classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the native SQL query runs in less than a millisecond. So stick with that. But that doesn't mean you have to wrestle with the List that comes from `query.getResultList()`.

You can execute a native query (either from [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) or from [`EntityManager.createNamedQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery(java.lang.String)) referring to a [`@NamedNativeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html)) and still have JPA construct your objects for you.

Specify a [`@SqlResultSetMapping`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) designating which `@Entity` classes you wish to use, and they will be created for you from the results of the query. I don't know your schema or entities, so I'm afraid I can't go farther than that at the moment. If your `@Entity` classes are appropriately configured and there are no duplicate column names in your resultset, it **can** be as simple as

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MyNativeQuery",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity1.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity2.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity3.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity4.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity5.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity6.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity7.class)
    }
)
```

but you will probably need to include the `fields` parameter to `@EntityResult`, providing a listing of `@FieldResult` items, to get everything right.

Comment: Tried that approach but it throws `SQLException: Column 'configur1_96_0_' not found`. What I tried to do: http://pastebin.com/UprSbNJE

Comment: You define that gigantic SQL query in the `sql` string and then you don't use it. Is that on purpose? Furthermore, do you - anywhere - have a column by that name? Is it being used by an `@Entity`?

Comment: That's how I did before using SqlResultSetMapping, just to show what's the SQL I want to return. No column is named 'configur1_96_0_' anywhere.

Comment: You should keep doing the same query, if you're mapping all of the columns from it into entity fields. How do you expect it to get the value for `Gondola.data_hora_inicial` (for example) if it's not in the query being executed?

Comment: Got it. Even passing the query ( `nq = em.createNativeQuery(sql, "ResultadoJoin");` ), the same exception is thrown. Tried not defining the fields, selecting `r.*, p.*` etc, but then the message was `Column 'equipe_id' not found.` And this column is from a `JoinTable` which I didn't put in the query.

Comment: When I add it to the original query (plus in `SqlResultSetMapping`), same error: Column 'configur1_96_0_' not found. Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/MRPN4iT6

Comment: I'm about out of ideas, but three more things... 1) Have you executed your SQL query by hand? 2) Have you spell-checked all of your field-mappings? 3) (Less likely) Are the variables in your entities named with underscores? Camel-case (`myFavoriteVariable` instead of my_favorite_variable) is more usual, is why I ask.